# Need proper SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such a table in MySQL db. I need a query to make a table of clients(columns), 12 months(rows) and data inside should be the sum of income of that client, that month.

[image: database]
[image: db]

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when month(date) = 1 then income else 0 end) as month_01,
       sum(case when month(date) = 2 then income else 0 end) as month_02,
       . . . 
from t
where date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01'
group by id;
```

Note that the `where` clause limits the timeframe to a single year, which seems reasonable for what you want to do.

Comment: Great, this works. But can you somehow shorten the part with 12 months? Iterate through a table of months or something

Comment: @AndrewMoskovets
If you want a column for every month then you cannot shorten the above code. If you don't need a column for every month I would suggest something like this:

`select id, month(date),
       sum(income) as sum_income
from t
where date >= '2019-01-01' and date < '2020-01-01'
group by id, month(date);`

You could also try to pivot the result from this query and get a column for every month...